# Recursion for finding the smallest path of numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

i have the array `[0,1,3,4,1]`. With this array I need to write a recursive function that either:

1. Goes to the next element, or
2. Skips the next element and goes to the one after it (can only skip a max of 1 element)

the condition being that it needs to be the smallest number possible. The solution to this problem is as follows:

- start at 0
- skip `1` and go to `3`
- skip `4` and go to `1`
- add the unskipped elements and return it

I have started the function with its base case:

```
private int play(int[] a, int first, int last) {
    int result = 0;

    // base case
    if (first == last){
        return a[first];
    }
    else{
        //result = play(a,first+1,last);
        //System.out.println(result);
    }
    return result;

}
```

with `first = 0` and `last = array_length -1`. Note, the array can have any number of elements, so say if I had the array `[0 4 23 566 34 45 555 11 34 35 45 65 55 98 344]` the lowest total would be 591.

Please bear with me, I am new to this recursion thing. Thanks in advance

Comment: So its suppose to return the numbers that you don't skip over all added up?

Comment: @3kings yes that is correct

Comment: So you are allowed to skip numbers, but never skip more than one number in a row?

Comment: @tobias_k yes, the function cannot skip more than one element

Comment: You are on the right track, you just need to determine if the recursive call uses first+1 or first+2 (using the condition you mentioned). Hint: beware case where first+2 would be beyond last.

Comment: Why in your example do you skip the first 1?  1 is less than 3, wouldn't it be better to return the 1 instead of the 3?

Comment: @markspace the program is supposed to skip `1` in the beginning since it wants the lowest sum of all unskipped elements. Therefore by skipping `1` we also skip `4`. 1+3 = 4; 4 is the smallest number combination.

Comment: OK, so this is a backtracking problem.  You have to find the shortest path (sum) through the array.  Have you looked at backtracking?

Comment: @markspace im pretty new to this recursion thing so i dont really know what backtracing is

Comment: Your professor may have given you a bad homework question, this looks pretty sophisticated to me.  I think you should ask your prof about it, there's something you or we aren't getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this where you keep track of what current index you are currently on and the sum so far up to the point of that index following the path (so the sum would exclude the numbers we skipped).

```
public static int play(int[] a, int index, int sum){
    if (index>=a.length) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;  //Path went over last index. Invalid Path. 
    sum += a[index];  //Add on to the sum of the index you are currently on
    if (index == a.length-1){
        return sum;  //If we are at last element, return sum of the path traveled
    }else{
        return Math.min(play(a, index+1, sum), play(a, index+2, sum)); //Continue onto path checking both options
    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] a = new int[]{0, 4, 23, 566, 34, 45, 555, 11, 34, 35, 45, 65, 55, 98, 344};
    System.out.println(play(a, 0, 0));
}
```

Output: `591`

Hope this helps.

Edit:
Okay, removing all the code and just thinking about this logically. The way I like to think of recursion (especially with paths) is that I am sending out individual little men and after each recursion I am going to duplicate those little men to take different paths. Lets use the smaller array, `[0,1,3,4,1]`, for this example.

We start off with one little man. He starts off at `0`. He has 2 options. First option is to go to `1` and second option is to go to `3`. We need to go down both of these paths since we are unsure what lies ahead. The little man duplicates himself sending one person to `1` and another to `3`.

Now the little man that went to path `1` has 2 more options laying ahead. He can either go to `3` or `4`. The little man that went to path `3` also has 2 more options. He can go to `4` or `1`. So they duplicate themselves and send the little men through all the options. I'm hoping this all makes sense at this point. The code that handles the duplication of the little man to different paths is: `play(a, index+1, sum), play(a, index+2, sum))`

What does a little man do once it reaches the end of the path? He has to tell the original little man how far the path is. The code for this is: `if (index == a.length-1){return sum;}`

The original little man, though, doesn't care about that one path. He needs to compare it to the counterpart that went the other path to see which one is shorter. That is controlled by the `Math.Min`. Which just returns the shorter distance of the 2 little men. So the little man that has the shorter of the distances kills his clone (:p) since we do not like that path. Eventually all of the little men will kill each other leaving only one little man standing which is the shortest distance. :)

Comment: this function does indeed work, but I have a midterm to attend to. Could you explain the function step by step? I would really like to understand how recursion works.

Comment: @user3170251 yup for sure.  I'll add some more text. Let me know if there is a specific section you are not understanding.

Comment: @user3170251 let me know if that at all makes sense. It is a little hard to teach this over text. :p

Comment: this example is brilliant. I'm definitely saving this explanation for possible future projects.

Comment: quick question code-wise, why is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` used

Comment: @user3170251 when you are at the second to last index in the array, you have two options: one to go to the end of the path (last index) and one to go past the path. The one that goes past the path (`index>=a.length`), we know is automatically out of the contest for the shortest path because it isn't even a path, so you set the sum to the max integer value so that when do the comparison with Math.Min it will always lose. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93016/discussion-between-gonzo-and-user3170251).